# Change pinvoke SHFileOperation root directory

Tags: vb.net, pinvoke

This is probably a question that nobody even know what I am talking about... But here it goes.

So, I want to delete, copy, move, and rename files using the actual Windows confirmation dialogs.
I am using [SHFileOperation](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/SHFileOperation.html). My problem is, that, when I want to move a folder with this path:
"C:\MyFolderToMove"
And I set the destination to:
"C:\Users\Test"
And **(THIS PART IS IMPORTANT)** the **APPLICATION** start from say
"D:\MyApp.exe"
SHFileOperation will try to move it to:
"D:\C\Users\Test"

So, it basically combines the "start-in" folder of the application with the destination you specify.

Does ANYONE have an idea of how to resolve this?
Here's the code, just in case someone wants to see it. (It's in VB.NET, but I also understand C#.NET.)

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Namespace SHFileOperation

    Public Module SHFileOperation

        Private Declare Function SHFileOperation Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "SHFileOperation" (ByRef lpFileOp As SHFILEOPSTRUCT) As Integer

        <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> _
        Private Structure SHFILEOPSTRUCT
            Public hwnd As IntPtr
            Public wFunc As Operation
            <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> _
            Public pFrom As String
            <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> _
            Public pTo As String
            Public fFlags As FileOperationFlags
            Public fAnyOperationsAborted As Boolean
            Public hNameMappings As IntPtr
            <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> _
            Public lpszProgressTitle As String '  only used if FOF_SIMPLEPROGRESS
        End Structure

        <Flags()> Public Enum FileOperationFlags
            FOF_MULTIDESTFILES = &H1
            FOF_CONFIRMMOUSE = &H2
            FOF_SILENT = &H4
            FOF_RENAMEONCOLLISION = &H8
            FOF_NOCONFIRMATION = &H10
            FOF_WANTMAPPINGHANDLE = &H20
            FOF_ALLOWUNDO = &H40
            FOF_FILESONLY = &H80
            FOF_SIMPLEPROGRESS = &H100
            FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR = &H200
            FOF_NOERRORUI = &H400
            FOF_NOCOPYSECURITYATTRIBS = &H800
            FOF_NORECURSION = &H1000
            FOF_NO_CONNECTED_ELEMENTS = &H2000
            FOF_WANTNUKEWARNING = &H4000
            FOF_NORECURSEREPARSE = &H8000
        End Enum

        Public Enum Operation As UInteger
            Move = &H1
            Copy = &H2
            Delete = &H3
            Rename = &H4
        End Enum

        Public Sub MoveFiles(ByVal File As String(), ByVal DestinationDirectory As String)
            Dim Struct As New SHFILEOPSTRUCT With {.hwnd = Nothing,
                                                   .wFunc = Operation.Move,
                                                   .pTo = DestinationDirectory & "\test",
                                                   .fFlags = FileOperationFlags.FOF_ALLOWUNDO Or FileOperationFlags.FOF_WANTNUKEWARNING}

            Dim Files As New Text.StringBuilder()
            For Each F As String In File
                Files.AppendFormat("{0}" & vbNullChar, F)
            Next
            Struct.pFrom = Files.ToString

            SHFileOperation(Struct)
        End Sub
        Public Sub MoveFiles(ByVal File As String, ByVal DestinationDirectory As String)
            MoveFiles(New String() {File}, DestinationDirectory)
        End Sub

    End Module

End Namespace
```

Comment: You fumbled the value of the DestinationDirectory argument.  It is not clear how, it isn't in the snippet.  Consider using My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveDirectory instead.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I am completely sure that I am sending the correct path. I am not even dynamically setting it, just paying a static string. as for using that other function, that one can only move one directory at a time, I will later on need to move multiple files and directories.

Comment: "I am completely sure that I am sending the correct path." Well, apparently you are not. If you were then the function would work. Look again.

Answer (score 2):

Your destination directory isn't double-null terminated (see the documentation for [SHFILEOPSTRUCT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759795.aspx)). Change the code to:

```
.pTo = DestinationDirectory & "\test" & vbNullChar,
```